# Verilog wire to register

Tags: input, output, verilog, bidirectional, bus

I have a bidirectional bus and I can read the inputs from it into wires, but I have a hard time do logic with them and assign them back on the BUS as an output, or connecting them into registers so I could work with the values.

All help and response is appreciated.

Jozsó

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic classes of variables in verilog: `net`s and `reg`s. `reg` is used to do calculations in procedural blocks, `net`s are used to connect different entities such as module instances or UDPs.

So, they have different functions and different rules and operators. So, wires are connected through module instance ports and/or a continuous `assign` operators, which ideally represent wire connections.

The basic rule are

1. a `net` value can be used as a rhs of a register expression. So, it can be assigned to a register within a procedural (e.g. always) block.
2. a `reg` value can be assign to a net in a continuous `assign` operator, or in an output port connection.
3. `net` cannot be assigned any value within an always block
4. `reg` cannot be assigned with a continuous assignment

The basic scheme to work around it is the following:

`wire --> always block ( reg ) --> assign (wire)`

Here is an example:

```
module top (bus, en);
   inout wire bus;
   input wire en;
    
   reg tmp;
  
   always @*
     tmp = bus;

  assign bus = en ? tmp : 1'bz;

endmodule
```

Comment: Hi Serge, Thank you for you response! It was very helpful, I appreciate it. I think I got with the software to the point I needed to, off to the next task. :)

Comment: @Jozsó if this post answered you question, please mark it as such. Thanks.